# How can I turn a array into a smaller array? in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "hassan",
    "last_name": "hassani",
    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:01",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "mohamad",
    "last_name": "mohamadi",
    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
  }
]
```

and i want to convert this array to array like this

```
[
  {
    "first_name" : "hassan",
    "last_name" : "hassani",
  },
  {
    "first_name" : "mohamad",
    "last_name" : "mohamadi",
  }
]
```

how i can do it ?

Thank you for answering

Comment: What have yo done so far?

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: The better place is you sql query to  remove some columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will resolve your issue. You can use the array_map() function to iterate each value.

```
 $result = array_map( function( $value ) {
       return [ 'first_name'=>$value['first_name'], 'last_name'=> $value['last_name'] ];
    }, $array );
    print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => hassan
            [last_name] => hassani
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => mohamad
            [last_name] => mohamadi
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the items from the arrays using the keys `id` and `created`:

```
$result = array_map(function($x) {
    unset($x['id'], $x['created']);
    return $x;
}, $arrays);
```

That will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => hassan
            [last_name] => hassani
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => mohamad
            [last_name] => mohamadi
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/U2voi)

Answer (score 0):

What have you already tried yourself? I understand that this stuff can be hard when you're (relatively) new to php and/or programming -- I am assuming you are, otherwise this question should really be deleted.

Here's some [good information](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) on arrays and how to loop over them. Check it out! W3C generally has some good and comprehensible information...

---

I'd go about this by looping over the array and removing all the entries that you don't want to keep -- i.e. aren't in an array of keys you want to keep. Alternatively you could you do it by specifying the keys that need to be deleted. For example:

```
<?php
$array = [
  [
    "id" => "2",
    "first_name" => "hassan",
    "last_name" => "hassani",
    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:01",
  ],
  [
    "id": "3",
    "first_name" => "mohamad",
    "last_name" => "mohamadi",
    "created" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
  ]
]

$keepers = ["first_name", "last_name"]; // Make an array of keys we want to keep.

foreach ($array as $arr) { // Loop over the outer array 
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value){ // Loop over the inner array that actually holds the key=> value pairs.
    if (!in_array($key, $keepers)){ // Determine whether we want to keep this key.
      unset($arr[$key]) // This key is not in the $keepers-array, we'll go ahead and delete (i.e. unset) it.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of ways to go about doing such, this is the first thing that came to mind for me however. Re-do the array. The method I will provide below will give you an example of how to do that without overwriting your current array, in case you need it later down the road. This method is also flexible.

```
<?php
$array = Array(); //you won't need this, let's just assume we're using the array from your original post

$newArray = Array(); //create a new array, this will have less values than the original

foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
    if ($k == "first_name" or $k == "last_name"){ //only add to array if the key is "first_name" or "last_name"
        $newArray[$k] = $v; //adds it to $newArray
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Best of luck to you! Also please note, I didn't test this code.

Comment: He has a multidimensional array, looping over it like this will give integers for `$k`. You need to loop over the array `$v` to actually manipulate the key=>value pairs... Or am I mistaking here?

Comment: @Niellles I'm not certain. If he printed this array from his PHP script I'm fairly certain that it would've outputted the number index aswell (that isn't within the array's values of course).